# ggplot scale alpha to only one variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a straightforward way to use `alpha` on only one variable using `ggplot2`?

I would have imagined that `scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0, 1))` would work like `scale_color_manual()`. Ultimately, I am interested in doing an animation where a colour appears gradually.

```
df = data.frame(time = 1:100, x1 = rnorm(100, 1, 5), x2 = rnorm(100, 1, 5)) %>% 
  melt(id.vars = 'time') 

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time, value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'blue')) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

I am trying to get something like this but with an `alpha`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `alpha` as an aesthetic:

```
df = data.frame(time = 1:100, x1 = rnorm(100, 1, 5), x2 = rnorm(100, 1, 5)) %>% 
  melt(id.vars = 'time') 

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time, value, colour = variable, alpha=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'blue')) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.3, 1))
```

[image]